# How to Change position length menu of Datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

Can I move length menu to beside `search part` label ?

Can I move the `length` with CSS only ? Or we need dom basic as like [this discussion](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5030/change-the-position-of-length-menu) I was try it but I don't know how to move with specify position

[image]

here is my following code to init datatable:

```
  table = $('#sparepart_id').DataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "stateSave": true,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "lengthChange": true,
        "searching": false,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": false,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "pageLength": 25,
        scrollX: true,
       stateLoadCallback: function (settings) {
         var o;
         $.ajax( {
            url     : BASE_URL+"spareparts/load_layout",
            type    : "POST",
            data    : { module_table : "sparepart-list"},
            async   : false,
            dataType: 'json',
             success: function (json) {
                 o = JSON.parse(json.json);
             },
             error:function(data){
                console.log(data);
             }
         } );
         return o;
     }
```

Comment: [SOLVED] thank you

Comment: You can post your solution (i.e answer your own question) and mark it as accepted answer.  Perhaps it can help other people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
} );
```

} );

For More Information :
https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/dom.html

Answer (score 0):

My Solution :

i just inspect element and looking what class in length menu `datatable` then put css code in my view

```
      .dataTables_length{
        margin-top : -57px;
        margin-left: 20px;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

move with specifying position should use `dom` property. There is an example may be helpful.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
     "dom": '<"toolbox"l>rtip',
     //... your another config,
     "initComplete":function(){
          //build your search layout here
         $(".toolbox").append("<label>search part</label><input>");         
     }
} );
```

`l` means `Length changing` feature, `<"toolbox"l>` will becomes

```html
<div class="toolbox">
    {Length changing}
    <label>search part</label><input>
</div>"
```

`{Length changing}` build by DataTables, you don't need care about it.

For More Information : https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/dom.html