# How to change position of lengthMenu in Shiny DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Like [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775014/how-to-change-position-length-menu-of-datatable), I need to alter the position of my lengthMenu option in my datatable. However, I am using Shiny and am not very well versed in JS. How can I move the lengthMenu from the bottom of my table to the top?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DTOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl <- renderDT(
      DT::datatable(iris,
                    selection = "none",
                    plugins = "ellipsis",
                    escape = FALSE,
                    rownames = FALSE,
                    options = list(
                      dom = 'rtipl', #https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom
                      scrollX=TRUE,
                      autoWidth = TRUE,
                      searching=FALSE,
                      ordering=TRUE,
                      bFilter = FALSE,
                      pageLength = 20,
                      lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50))
      ))
    # )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `dom = 'rtipl'` to `dom = 'lrtip'`. The letter `l` denotes the length menu.